# Showing that $ye^{x/y} = \max_{\alpha>0} \left[ \alpha(x+y) - y\alpha \log(\alpha) \right]$

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

In my optimization textbook, the author states without proof that

$$
ye^{x/y} = \max_{\alpha>0} \left[ \alpha(x+y) - y\alpha \log(\alpha) \right].
$$

To be honest, this does not seem very obvious to me. Could someone explain why this is true?

Further, how might I verify that this function is convex? (The section that I'm reading involves optimizing a set of convex functions.)

Thanks.

Comment: It's convex (in x and y) because it's the maximum of convex functions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:\alpha\mapsto\alpha(x+y)-y\alpha\log\alpha$.

We have $$\frac{df(\alpha)}{d\alpha}=x+y-y(\log\alpha+1)$$ and

$$\frac{d^2f(\alpha)}{d\alpha^2}=-\frac{y}{\alpha}$$

If $y>0$, then $f$ is strictly concave because in this case $f''<0$. To find the maximum you solve $f'(\alpha)=0$, which leads to $\alpha^*=e^{\frac{x}{y}}$.

Substituting in $f$, $f(\alpha^*)=ye^{\frac{x}{y}}$.